# Jquery focusout runs several time by each mouse out click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to validate the textbox by mouse out in jquery, my code is running by any mouse out means it shows  Enter valid Email. several times, any time that I click outside the textbox.
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#EmailAddress').focusout(function() {
        var email = $.trim($('#EmailAddress').val() || '');
        if (email.length == 0 || !emailregx.test(email)) {
            $(this).addClass('ChangetoYellow');
            $(this).after('<div class="Required">Enter valid Email.</div>');
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).next(".Required").remove();
            $(this).removeClass('ChangetoYellow');
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

my code is not working when it is outside the document.ready.

This is what I get when I run by each time I click:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented some code to validate text box and insert error div after the element if entered value is not valid.

I hope below code will solve your problem

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#EmailAddress').focusout(function() {
        var email = $.trim($('#EmailAddress').val() || '');
        if (email.length == 0 || !emailregx.test(email)) {
            var errorLabel = errorsFor(this);
            $(this).addClass('ChangetoYellow');
            if(errorLabel.length > 0){
             $(errorLabel).show();
            }
            else {
             $(this).after('<div for='+ this.name +' class="required">Enter valid Email.</div>');
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).next(".required").remove();
            $(this).removeClass('ChangetoYellow');
            return true;
        }
    });
  
  
    function errorsFor( element ) {
   var name = idOrName(element);
   return $('.required').filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("for") === name;
   });
  };

    function idOrName( element ) {
   return element.name ? element.name : element.id || element.name;
    };
});
```

[Test sample code](https://jsfiddle.net/mhjadav/kbouoo9a/1/)

Answer (score 3):

```
$(this).after('<div class="Required">Enter valid Email.</div>');
```

this will add a new  after every focus out of the input box.

Instead have a placeholder div below the text box.

```
<div id="emailErrorMsg"></div>
```

and do

```
$('#emailErrorMsg').html('Enter valid Email.');
```

this will also let you add more error messages.

Comment: $(#emailErrorMsg) should have Quotes on it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the div before you add one to prevent repeats.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#EmailAddress').focusout(function() {
        var email = $.trim($('#EmailAddress').val() || '');
        if (email.length == 0 || !emailregx.test(email)) {
            $(this).addClass('ChangetoYellow');
            if($(this).next().hasClass('Required'))
                $(this).next().remove();
            $(this).after('<div class="Required">Enter valid Email.</div>');
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).next(".Required").remove();
            $(this).removeClass('ChangetoYellow');
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This one first remove previous error messages and add it.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#EmailAddress').focusout(function() {
      var email = $.trim($('#EmailAddress').val() || '');
      if (email.length == 0  || !emailregx.test(email)) {
         $(this).parent().find(".Required").remove();
         $(this).addClass('ChangetoYellow');
         $(this).after('<div class="Required">Enter valid Email.</div>');
         return false;
      } else {
         $(this).parent().find(".Required").remove();
         $(this).removeClass('ChangetoYellow');
         return true;
     }
  });
});
```

For Simple Example Fiddle (if u want add the regular expression and test it) - 
http://jsbin.com/pujemay/edit?html,js,output